# php matches any / match any operator equivalent

Tags: php, operators

I frequently find myself writing things like `if($var == 'bob' || $var == 'steven || $var == 'james'){ ...`

Is there a slicker way in php to check whether a var matches any operator?  Or do I have to write my own function like:

```
function matches_any($question, $pos_answer, $pos_answer, $pos_answer, $pos_answer, ...){
// Call the function args, get the first one, get the rest, compare all the rest, return true if any match, return false by default.
}
```

Which would be used thus:

```
if(matches_any($var, $bob, $steven, 'james', $william)){ ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`in_array()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.in-array.php)

```
if(in_array('value_to_test', array($var, $bob, $steven, 'james', $william))) {}

$matches = array($var, $bob, $steven, 'james', $william);
if (in_array('james', $matches)) { 
  // TRUE 
}
```

Comment: @yes123 Noticed and fixed before seeing your comment

Comment: Yeah, was planning on using in_array inside the custom function.  Was kinda hoping that there was a native php equivalent to my otherwise custom function, but I guess either using in_array in the place or using the custom function in the place is what I'll have to resort to.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should avoid hard-coding any values into your code -- if you keep content in data structures (=think 'config' or 'database'), you will minimize your chances for running into this problem because you're processing abstractions rather than specific values. This means changing your concept from "these are the definite people who can ever do this" into "let's ask another facility whether this guy can do this"

If you absolutely positively must have a function like what you described, you can do it with func_get_args():

```
function matches_any()
{
    $haystack = func_get_args();        
    $needle = array_shift( $haystack );

    return in_array( $needle, $haystack );
}
```

(Untested)

Comment: yeah, that matches_any was about what I was planning if I had to end up writing it myself.  But I really don't get your comment about hard-coded values?  I guess you mean things like 'bob' and 'james' as opposed to $bob and $james (just in case their content changes)?  If so, then yeah, I agree in general, those were just used as quick examples.  Oh, and I was only using names because that's what came to mind first, I think that you're saying that hard-coding access via names would be bad, which yeah, it would.  :D

Comment: My point was that if you constantly run into situations where you have to handle similar exhaustive 'if' clauses, then you should consider why you're running into them. It might be that by changing your approach you could entirely avoid the problem rather than having to find a way around it.

Comment: True, really I wasn't specific in the question, I usually tend to keep my code as simple as possible myself, but these days I'm doing a lot of refactoring of horrible code, which is where I encounter this kind of thing, and being able to simplify it down to a single short sentence would be of great benefit.